# Variable won't update out of function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Something is going wrong with my code, as my title implies.

This code is for a matching game, I separate the document into two (nodes) and generate smiley faces randomly on one side, then clone it to the other side. I remove the last child(face) on the RHS so that the user then has to click on the extra smiley on the LHS of the page to get to the next level, at which point 5 smileys are added to increase the difficulty. The user is supposed to click on the extra smiley to the left to pass to the next level.

Everything works except The adding of the smileys. 
THE PROBLEM IS THAT WHEN IT GOES TO THE NEXT LEVEL, it resets the number of faces to 5(or whatever the number that is set below with the same commented text) for some reason!

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
    <style>
        img {position:absolute;}
        /*here i tried to use 500px in the style rules for the div but the division was noticeably off centre, therefore, i used 50% instead*/
        div {position:absolute; width:50%; height:50%} 
        #rightSide {left:50%; border-left: 1px solid black}
    </style>

</head>
<body onload="generateFaces()">

<h1 id="TitleOfGame">Matching Game!</h1>
    <p id="Intructions">To play the game, find the extra smiley on the left hand side and click on it :)</p>
    <div id="leftSide">
    <!--this div node will display all of the faces on the left side of the screen
        faces are dynamically added using javascript-->
    </div>
    <div id="rightSide">
    <!--this div node will display all of the faces on the right side of the screen
        cloneNode(true) is used to copy the faces to the right side, and the last child of this branch is deleted, such that there are more faces on the left side.
    -->
    </div>
            <script>
            //this part of the script generates 5 faces randomly placed on the left side of the screen
        var numberOfFaces=5;
        var theLeftSide = document.getElementById("leftSide");
        var i=0;
        var theBody=document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0];
        function generateFaces(){
            while (i<numberOfFaces){
                var random_top=((Math.random()*400));
                var random_left=((Math.random()*400));
                var random_top=Math.floor(random_top);
                var random_left=Math.floor(random_left);
                var img=document.createElement('img');
                img.src="smile.png";
                img.style.left=random_left+"px";
                img.style.top=random_top+"px";
                theLeftSide.appendChild(img);   
                i+=1;
                        //this part of the script clones those 5 faces onto the right side of the page.
            var theRightSide=document.getElementById("rightSide");
            var leftSideImages = theLeftSide.cloneNode(true);
            }
            theRightSide.appendChild(leftSideImages);
               leftSideImages=leftSideImages.removeChild(leftSideImages.lastChild);
            theLeftSide.lastChild.onclick=function nextLevel(event) {
                event.stopPropagation();
                while (theLeftSide.firstChild) {
                    theLeftSide.removeChild(theLeftSide.firstChild);
                }
                while (theRightSide.firstChild) {
                theRightSide.removeChild(theRightSide.firstChild);
                }
                numberOfFaces++;  //OK SO THE PROBLEM IS THAT WHEN IT GOES TO THE NEXT LEVEL, IT RESETS numberOfFaces to 5(or whatever the number that is set here) for some reason!
                numberOfFaces++;  //adding manually like this gives the same result as x+=5. ie. the variable is not being updated, it is being reset.
                numberOfFaces++;
                numberOfFaces++;
                generateFaces();
            };
                theBody.onclick=function youFail() {
                    alert("Game Over!");
                    theBody.onclick=null;
                    theLeftSide.lastChild.onclick=null;
                };
        };
        </script>
</body>
</html>
```

There is no error flagged by the console..

Answer (score 0):

Try resetting your `i` variable to `0` inside the `generateFaces` function. You also add to the counter variable in the `generateFaces` function so unless you reset it you will never add the additional faces.

```js
//this part of the script generates 5 faces randomly placed on the left side of the screen
        var numberOfFaces=5;
        var theLeftSide = document.getElementById("leftSide");
        var i=0;
        
        var theBody=document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0];
        function generateFaces(){
            i = 0;
            while (i<numberOfFaces){
                var random_top=((Math.random()*400));
                var random_left=((Math.random()*400));
                var random_top=Math.floor(random_top);
                var random_left=Math.floor(random_left);
                var img=document.createElement('img');
                img.src="smile.png";
                img.style.left=random_left+"px";
                img.style.top=random_top+"px";
                theLeftSide.appendChild(img);   
                i+=1;
                        //this part of the script clones those 5 faces onto the right side of the page.
            var theRightSide=document.getElementById("rightSide");
            var leftSideImages = theLeftSide.cloneNode(true);
            }
            theRightSide.appendChild(leftSideImages);
            leftSideImages=leftSideImages.removeChild(leftSideImages.lastChild);
            theLeftSide.lastChild.onclick=function nextLevel(event) {
                event.stopPropagation();
                while (theLeftSide.firstChild) {
                    theLeftSide.removeChild(theLeftSide.firstChild);
                }
                while (theRightSide.firstChild) {
                theRightSide.removeChild(theRightSide.firstChild);
                }
                numberOfFaces++;  //OK SO THE PROBLEM IS THAT WHEN IT GOES TO THE NEXT LEVEL, IT RESETS numberOfFaces to 5(or whatever the number that is set here) for some reason!
                numberOfFaces++;  //adding manually like this gives the same result as x+=5. ie. the variable is not being updated, it is being reset.
                numberOfFaces++;
                numberOfFaces++;
                generateFaces();
            };
                theBody.onclick=function youFail() {
                    alert("Game Over!");
                    theBody.onclick=null;
                    theLeftSide.lastChild.onclick=null;
                };
        };
```

```css
img {position:absolute;}
        /*here i tried to use 500px in the style rules for the div but the division was noticeably off centre, therefore, i used 50% instead*/
        div {position:absolute; width:50%; height:50%} 
        #rightSide {left:50%; border-left: 1px solid black}
```

```html
<body onload="generateFaces()">

<h1 id="TitleOfGame">Matching Game!</h1>
    <p id="Intructions">To play the game, find the extra smiley on the left hand side and click on it :)</p>
    <div id="leftSide">
    <!--this div node will display all of the faces on the left side of the screen
        faces are dynamically added using javascript-->
    </div>
    <div id="rightSide">
    <!--this div node will display all of the faces on the right side of the screen
        cloneNode(true) is used to copy the faces to the right side, and the last child of this branch is deleted, such that there are more faces on the left side.
    -->
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: @J_Suntown did this answer your question?

Comment: Awesome :) glad that did it! Could you mark my answer as correct?